# How I can get recursive all directories and files in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use TYPO3 6.2.x
I have files folders and subfolders in some directory.
I can get all files recursive as

```
$files = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getAllFilesAndFoldersInPath(array(), $dirPath, '', 0, 99, '');
$files = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::removePrefixPathFromList($files, $dirPath);
```

I get following:

```
file1
file2
directory1/file1
directory1/file2
directory1/subdirectory/file1
```

I need to get files and directories as

```
file1
file2
  directory1    
    file1
    file2
  directory1/subdirectory/
    file1
```

How I can get recursive all directories and files in it?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `basename` method of PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Look at the examples, I think it suits your needs